# Magento 2 showing curly brace variables

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I have a really odd issue with one of our Magento 2 stores

It is displaying variables on the frontend and in the admin in random places

I can't see anything in php error logs, or Magento error logs, nor is there anything in the console to suggest what's wrong

Googling hasn't been much help either!

**Frontend**

[image]

**Backend**

[image]

Comment: try to clear browser cache one and then try.

Comment: Given it a try and incognito mode but no luck :(